# I am trying to implement Redux to my React Native app, as tutorials use ReactDOM.render() method, and I cannot seem to locate it,

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux

As mentioned I am building a react-native app, and want to implement Redux, I am already deep into my project, using stack-navigator some api calls, aync storage and more. However every tutorial I watch regarding redux, ends up manipulating the ReactDOM.render() method, typicall inside a index.js file. However I cannot seem to find mine in my project, any help would be greatly appreciated. Link to the repo:

https://github.com/mattyjjpearce/trackerApp/tree/filterFetch

ps: latest version is the filterFetch branch

Kindest Regards,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Create a new component under `App.js` and wrap the `Navigator` with a `Provider`

```
const App = createAppContainer(Navigator);
export default () => (<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>)
```